# Authorize redirect request after user Allow access to his files in Dropbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, dropbox-api

I'm writing web app using **Asp.Net Web Api**. My app fetching user files from Dropbox. To do it user first must allow access to his storage (usual behaviour for OAuth2). The problem is I cannot get authorized user (in controller action in my app) after "Allow" redirect because this redirect doesn`t contain **Authorization** header with Bearer token (which is required for my app). I need my application user id to store access token (from Dropbox) for him.

I'm using DropboxRestAPI library for access Dropbox Api (https://github.com/saguiitay/DropboxRestAPI)

Here is controller action that accept redirect with user code from Dropbox:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public void AuthoriseDropbox(string code = null, string error = null) {
        var options = new Options {
            ClientId = "...",
            ClientSecret = "..."
        };

        var client = new Client(options);
        var token = await client.Core.OAuth2.TokenAsync(code);

        // save token in Db for current user

        // will be null because request from Dropbox without Authorization token
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); 
        // store token for particular user
        ...
    }
```

The only solution I know is to send token as responce and make authorized request with that token.

But what is better solution in this case?

Thanks

Comment: I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with the library you're using. The user ID is indeed returned at the end of the auth flow, but perhaps this library doesn't expose it. You can call [`/account/info`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#account-info) to get the Dropbox user ID if you want.

Comment: I can get Dropbox user Id successfully using token, but i need to get my app user Id from Web Api Identity system

Comment: Oh, sorry, I can't help with that. Presumably that would be done with cookies. Consider removing the dropbox-api tag.

Comment: Yeah, i think cookies is better solution, I'll try, thanks.